# Is it possible to create a blockchain with probabilistic finality with substrate?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, bitcoin, substrate

Substrate depends on finality for its block production by default. Looking also into the application database layer with blocks, it seems that block reverting isn't normally possible with arbitrary depth. Does that mean it's impossible to have probabilistic finality in substrate?

**Context to the problem:**

In Bitcoin, Ethereum and other probabilistic-finality-based chains, the chain can reorg with as many blocks as the system needs. It can even be thousands of blocks if need be. Consequently, the [state transition function](https://docs.substrate.io/v3/concepts/runtime/) (using substrate terminology) must be reversible. Hence, when a reorg happens, blocks are reverted in a way where (in bitcoin), outputs are removed and inputs become unspent in the UTXO set.

In the most abstract form, this can be functionally represented as:

```
Apply(StateA, blockX)  -> StateB

Revert(StateB, blockX) -> StateA
```

This strictly requires that it's known how a revert is done, given a block. In bitcoin, this is easily achievable as we know exactly how to "unspend" inputs and delete outputs by a simple database change.

**The current situation in substrate (as far as I understand it):**

But in a general purpose chain like substrate, this cannot be done without storing the set of [state changes per block](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/540b4fd0f6bf8157f5402f0095f78f0ed893c57b/primitives/database/src/lib.rs#L32) over the whole blockchain, which has a huge diskspace/memory requirement (called archive-pruning mode in substrate). Or, the developer has to provide the mechanism for reversibility, which doesn't seem to be a requirement in the [pallet standard interface](https://docs.substrate.io/v3/runtime/frame/#pallets), as people are only required to provide the changes that have to be done in the database only when applying a block, not when removing/reverting a block from the tip of the mainchain.

As can be seen in the [database handling of a block](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/540b4fd0f6bf8157f5402f0095f78f0ed893c57b/client/db/src/lib.rs#L2146), it's not possible to revert an arbitrary number of blocks the same way it's possible in probabilistic finality blockchains (unless pruning mode is `archive`, which is impractical to assume for all users). Substrate seems to assume that finality is an inevitability, where in the technical underlying database/storage, the concept of ["canonicalization"](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/latest/sc_state_db/index.html) is defined. A canonicalized block is a block that's technically irrevertible/irreversible, because its state transaction function has been applied to the database. And given that pallets don't define any mechanism for reverting extrinsics/transactions and hence blocks, there's absolutely no way to revert a block after it gets canonicalized. So, substrate stores a tree of all possible block candidates that are not yet canonicalized/finalized.

This caused me lots of confusion because it seems that [substrate does support proof-of-work consensus](https://docs.substrate.io/rustdocs/latest/sc_consensus_pow/index.html), but the canonicalization concept completely eradicates the possibility to revert blocks, which is typically a requirement in proof of work due to its probabilistic nature. (and on a humorous note, congratulations, 51% attacks with shadow mining are not possible anymore :-), but on a serious note, spontaneous contentious forks and chain-splits are possible if a group of honest nodes get isolated long enough, which is not that unrealistic, e.g., if a country decides to block the internet for a few days or block the node ports for political reasons, which should never be a problem in normal proof-of-work systems).

**The question**

This question is based on the requirement of building a substrate-based blockchain that follows bitcoin.

Is it possible to make substrate consensus completely operate with correct probabilistic finality (without canonicalization and with proper definitions of reversible operations)? What would have to be changed? Is it a realistic change or is it drilled to the bones such that it's practically impossible? I honestly don't know where to start and would like to get an overview of the changes that have to be done to make the substrate blockchain work with probabilistic finality.

Comment: I think you should ask this on one of the substrate communities. You will get a quicker response from people who actually know what they are talking about.

Comment: @PeterHall I totally agree with you. It's already posted in Substrate's Element/Matrix chat. The purpose of this write-up is just to have it as a consistent and complete write-up, as substrate doesn't have dedicated forums; at least AFAIK. Besides that they encourage using SO.

Comment: ok fair enough!

Comment: Far from entering in details, I would like to point out that the pallets in charge of block production and finality are optional to use. That's one of the pros of substrate, it is open for customization and within that customization enters how production and finalization works for your case.
So, the easy answer here would be yes why not as long as you want to implement it if its not yet done.
And on the other side you will have to check the requirements for your case to see if moving away of the current implementation is something feasible, in case you want to.

Comment: @AlejandroMartínez It seems that there's huge confusion that people mix finalization and canonicalization. They're not the same, and my question basically says "finalization can be removed from substrate, but canonicalization cannot be removed... which makes probabilistic finality impossible".

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist can you please take a look at the Substrate StackExchange proposal and support it: https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/126136

Comment: @ShawnTabrizi Hi Shawn. I actually do support the proposal as I believe substrate needs its dedicated forum, but I can't officially "commit" because I can't commit to answering/asking questions there for a long time, as this seems to be the requirement. Apologies.

Comment: Once the new StackExchange goes live, we will be migrating our Substrate Technical Channel support questions to this format, so there will be plenty of questions and answers being populated by the community. We just need your support as a user with 200+ reptuation. I am sure this will not be your last question about substrate, and thus you will certainly use the site in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will post this answer since the only other answer available in this post is wrong and the comments seem to be overseen.

The answer is no. Substrate, with its canonicalization of the database that can happen even before finalization, it's not possible to have a proper proof of work blockchain, as it's impossible to reverse blocks after canonicalization.

It was decided by the management of the project I'm working with to move off substrate because of this issue. [Technical details here](https://www.mintlayer.org/en/news/2022-02-01-mintlayer-moves-off-substrate/).

I'm posting this information about substrate regardless of whether this design good or bad, it's what it's. I can see pros and cons to it.

Comment: Hey, your blog post got some of us at Parity Technologies talking, and we think there are some points which you did not get quite right. I believe we have reached out to discuss things with you, if you would like that.

Comment: @ShawnTabrizi Hi Shawn. We checked all our emails and found nothing. Can you please email Benjamin Marsh and we'll arrange a meeting? I kind of fail to find a way to communicate without disclosing contact information publicly, which I'm trying to avoid to avoid spam. Feel free to suggest any other way for contact.

Comment: You can email me at shawn@parity.io

Answer (score 1):

I believe https://kulupu.network/ is a substrate chain based on PoW with probabilistic finality.

Here's an older example of implementing UTXO in substrate: https://www.parity.io/blog/utxo-on-substrate/

Finally another interesting project is https://github.com/interlay/interbtc which do a BTC bridge so that parachain is likely to be aligned with bitcoin conventions.

Do these help?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Unfortunately, this is a wrong answer and targets the wrong issue. Yes, you can nominally build PoW in Substrate. I've explained actually in my question that this is nominally possible and provided a link to the pallet that allows that. That's not correct PoW though. Being able to work to produce blocks isn't the only condition required to have a correct PoW chain. As it stands, there's no way to do long reorgs due to canonicalization, which creates the problems I mentioned in the question (possible chainsplits, winner isn't really the longest chain, etc).

Comment: Have a look at historical sessions in the session pallet. It seems like pruning can be configured back a certain distance in history. That might be a halfway house to running full archive?

Comment: Yes, of course, you can control the depth of canonicalization. But still, it will happen eventually and prevent deep reorgs to protect memory.